# Javascript Array - Split string at numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

I have an unknown string containing a set of numbers like so:

```
var string = "stuff 1.23! (456) 789 stuff";
```

I would like to split the array, in order to modify the numbers and later rejoin the array. The result I'm looking for should look like this:

```
var result = ['stuff ', 1.23, '! (', 456, ') ', 789, ' stuff'];
```

Is there a better solution than to loop through each character individually? Thanks!

Comment: `string.split(/(\d+)/)`

Comment: why not use replace?

Comment: The best solution really depends on what in the world you are actually doing. I mean I can open up a window with a hammer, but if I need to close it, it might not be the best solution.

Comment: There's no single RegExp or String method, which could create the result you need (an array with mixed types). Hence you have to map the resulted array to change the numeric strings to numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a character class to split the values:

```
/(-?[\d.]+)/
```

- `-?` May start with a negative such as `-123`
- `[\d.]+` Has one or more numbers and decimals

```js
var string = "stuff 1.23! (456) 789 stuff -234".split(/(-?[\d.]+)/);

console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution really depends on what exactly you are doing with the data. One simple solution is a regular expression with replace.

```js
var string = "stuff 1.23! (456) 789 stuff";
var updated = string.replace(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g, function (m) {
  console.log(m);
  return "xxx";
})
console.log(updated)
```

Answer (score -1):

A [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is an expression you can use to search within your string, in you case, for digits. [Create a regular expression](https://regex101.com/) which searches for sequences of digits, and you'll be able to use the [split method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) on your string to create an array of strings like you specified.